# Need a probabilistic approach to determine if a data-set A includes all the elements of data-set B

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, data-analysis

My job is to identify if the two given datasets are same. This is to be done on computers using some programming language (C++).

Since the data could be huge, I don't want to read all the elements of one set and compare with the other one. I guess, it is okay, if one could tell me that there is, for example, 95% probability that two data sets are same or that one is subset of the other.
I want some mathematical/probabilistic/statistical method of comparison where I don't have to perform a brute force method.

Comment: You might get a great answer here, but [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) seems perfect for this question.

Comment: Have you looked into Bloom Filters?  They're like probabilistic hash tables, something like that could work for you.

Comment: @hacatu Yes I have, they don't server the purpose as I still need to read all elements from one set. Bloom Filter handles membership problem for single element not for a complete set.